# Magento 2.4 - How can I add a custom message to product pages when they have zero inventory?

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.4

I would like to show a custom message on the product page when a product has zero qty in stock.

Can someone help?

Custom message on the product page when product has zero qty.

If possible custom message can replace the in stock message but only with zero qty products.